# Rake test not picking up capybara tests in minitest

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capybara, minitest

I am setting up a basic template for having a capybara feature test in a rails application. I'm also using MiniTest instead of RSPEC.

Running Rake Test does not seem to be picking up my feature tests. I have one test in the file, running rake test does not change the number of assertions. Skipping the test does not show up either when I run rake test.

Here is a link to the repository: https://github.com/rrgayhart/rails_template

Here are the steps that I followed

1. I added this to the Gemfile and ran bundle

   ```
   group :development, :test do
     gem 'capybara'
     gem 'capybara_minitest_spec'
     gem 'launchy'
   end
   ```
2. I added this to the test_helper

   ```
   require 'capybara/rails'
   ```
3. I created a folder test/features
4. I created a file called drink_creation_test.rb
5. Here is the code from that feature test file

   ```
   require 'test_helper'

   class DrinkCreationTest < MiniTest::Unit::TestCase

     def test_it_creates_an_drink_with_a_title_and_body
         visit drinks_path
         click_on 'new-drink'
         fill_in 'name', :with => "PBR"
         fill_in 'description', :with => "This is a great beer."
         fill_in 'price', :with => 7.99
         fill_in 'category_id', :with => 1
         click_on 'save-drink'
         within('#title') do
           assert page.has_content?("PBR")
         end
         within('#description') do
           assert page.has_content?("td", text: "This is a great beer")
         end
     end

   end
   ```

I think I am having an issue with not connecting something correctly. 
Please let me know if there is anything else I can provide which may help with diagnosing this issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Multiple things going on here. First, the default `rake test` task won't pick up tests not in the default test directories. So you need to either move the test file or add a new rake task to test files in `test/features`.

Since you are using [capybara_minitest_spec](https://github.com/ordinaryzelig/capybara_minitest_spec) you need to include `Capybara::DSL` and `Capybara::RSpecMatchers` into your test. And because you aren't using `ActiveSupport::TestCase` or one of the other Rails test classes in this test, you may see inconsistencies in the database because this test is executing outside of the standard rails test transactions.

```
require 'test_helper'

class DrinkCreationTest < MiniTest::Unit::TestCase
  include Capybara::DSL
  include Capybara::RSpecMatchers

  def test_it_creates_an_drink_with_a_title_and_body
      visit drinks_path
      click_on 'new-drink'
      fill_in 'name', :with => "PBR"
      fill_in 'description', :with => "This is a great beer."
      fill_in 'price', :with => 7.99
      fill_in 'category_id', :with => 1
      click_on 'save-drink'
      within('#title') do
        assert page.has_content?("PBR")
      end
      within('#description') do
        assert page.has_content?("td", text: "This is a great beer")
      end
  end

end
```

Or, you could use [minitest-rails](https://github.com/blowmage/minitest-rails) and [minitest-rails-capybara](https://github.com/blowmage/minitest-rails-capybara) to generate *and* run these tests.

```
$ rails generate mini_test:feature DrinkCreation
$ rake minitest:features
```

Comment: Excellent! This is the perfect answer - we were able to get the tests if we moved them to integration (which speaks to your rake task comment) - but finally moved over to moving the minitest specific gem. Thank you again!

Answer (score 2):

I believe minitest has it's own gem for rails when using capybara: [minitest-rails-capybara](https://github.com/blowmage/minitest-rails-capybara)

Following the instructions over there might help, but I've never set up capybara with mini test before.